# Insert function is giving 1004 error in excel macro vba

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is giving error (1004)

```
 Sheets(2).Cells(i, 7).Formula = "=LEFT(" & Sheets(2).Cells(i, 5) & ",2)"
```

Comment: Have you set `i` anywhere?

Comment: yes, the value of i=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the value of a cell to `LEFT`, which expects either a cell reference or a string (including the quotation marks). Try

`Sheets(2).Cells(i, 7).Formula = "=LEFT(" & Sheets(2).Cells(i, 5).Address & ",2)"`

or

`Sheets(2).Cells(i, 7).Formula = "=LEFT(""" & Sheets(2).Cells(i, 5) & """,2)"`

instead.